# Comparator.comparing doesnt deduce right type for input

Tags: java, generics

I have object Person:

```
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    Date birth;
    //getters and setters
}

List<Person> persons = retrievePersons();
```

Now i want to sort it according to birth(MM/DD/YY format) such as first sorting parameter will be month and second day.

I tried using

```
int extractMonth(Date date){...}
int extractDay(Date date){...}

    persons= persons.stream()
            .sorted(
                    Comparator.comparing( element -> extractMonth(element.getBirth()))
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

this works, but when i add `thenComparing()`

```
    persons= persons.stream()
            .sorted(
                    Comparator.comparing( element -> extractMonth(element.getBirth()))
                    .thenComparing(element -> extractDay(element.getBirth())
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This results in errros:
`cannot resolve method getBirth()` in both of comparing methods.

Why is this happening? Callin Comparator.comparing should set T to `Person` in Comparing generics.

But if i specify input and output manually:

```
    persons= persons.stream()
            .sorted(
                    Comparator.<Person,Integer>comparing( element -> extractMonth(element.getBirth()))
                    .thenComparing(element -> extractDay(element.getBirth())
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It works... why?

Comment: Because that's how Java's type inference works. In an expression like `Comparator.comparing(...).thenComparing(...)`, it decides the type of the `Comparator.comparing(...)` first (and, absent any other constraints, that's a `Comparator<Object>`, or something similar).

Comment: `Date`... Please don't. Use classes from `java.time` instead.

Comment: @MCEmperor and don't represent a civil time concept using something that represents an instant, because your birthday doesn't change if you change time zone: `java.time.LocalDate` is the appropriate type here.

Comment: Exactly. [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api)

Answer (score -2):

Java needs help with parameter type inference if the object to be sorted doesn't appear as an explicit type anywhere in the lambda declaration.

In this case you can only infer that the Comparator is to compare `Person`s, because it is enclosed within an operation on the Person stream. Though I have no proof that this is what the compiler does, if you were looking only at the lines where you create the Comparator itself, there is no hint whatsoever that `Person` is ever involved. As such the only safe inference is that you're comparing `Object`.

What you can do is simply use `Comparator.comparingInt()` instead:

```
    persons= persons.stream()
        .sorted(
                Comparator.comparingInt( element -> extractMonth(element.getBirth()))
                .thenComparingInt(element -> extractDay(element.getBirth())
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This also works (declaring the initial object as a Person):

```
    persons= persons.stream()
        .sorted(
                Comparator.comparing( (Person element) -> extractMonth(element.getBirth()))
                .thenComparing(element -> extractDay(element.getBirth())
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or this (methods directly accept `Person`):

```
    int extractBirthMonth(Person p) {...}
    int extractBirthDay(Person p) {...}

    persons= persons.stream()
            .sorted(
                    Comparator.comparing( this::extractBirthMonth)
                    .thenComparing(this::extractBirthDay)
```